# how do i center content without the use of text-align:center

Tags: html, css, center

How do I center the content without the use of text-align:center;? My code below: The code below does not center the content. Thank you for your time.

```
<div class="feat_wrapper">
<div class="product_image">
<img src="landing_product.png" alt="sweater">   
</div>

<div class="content">
CITY SCAPE <br>SHIRTS   
</div>
</div>


.feat_wrapper{

margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;


}
```

Comment: This should about cover all of your options [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.feat_wrapper{
width:20%;
margin:0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="feat_wrapper">
<div class="product_image">
<img src="landing_product.png" alt="sweater">   
</div>

<div class="content">
CITY SCAPE <br>SHIRTS   
</div>
</div>
```

(only changes were in css)

I'm assuming you meant horizontally center, but if you meant vertically as well, please comment, and I will assist with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the width element of the div
for example:

```
.feat_wrapper{
  width:600px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

}